# Prevent ndk-build from automatically cleaning module

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-build

On my current setup (ndk r8c) `ndk-build` performs a clean step (`V=1` shows `rm` in action) without issuing `clean` explicitly. 
I'd like to change this behavior - I'm currently having linking problems and (re-)compilation takes more than 5 minutes. How can I do this?

Comment: This was fixed in NDK r8d.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you are fasing a bug of NDK r8c. See this thread: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39810. You can downgrade to a previous NDK release or apply the suggested patch.

The patch is to change a single line 289 in `build/core/definitions.mk` from

```
$1: $$(__ndk_file_dir)
```

to

```
$1: | $$(__ndk_file_dir)
```