# Every NDK build is a full rebuild

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent ndk-build from automatically cleaning module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788824/prevent-ndk-build-from-automatically-cleaning-module)

Android project with an NDK library. NDK r8c. Compiling under Cygwin (it's an old project).

A bunch of C++ and C files, and some .a libraries linked via LOCAL_LDLIBS.

Since some time ago, I'm noticing that every NDK build goes over all source files. Even if I call the ndk-build twice in a row, there's a full rebuild on second try. There's nothing to the effect in the .mk files that I can see, and the command I invoke to build is a vanilla `$NDKPATH/ndk-build`. There's no -B option anywhere.

The only wrinkle is this: on every build, NDK says the following:

```
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8c/build/core/add-application.mk:128: Android NDK: WARNING:
APP_PLATFORM android-9 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 3 in
/cygdrive/d/AppPath/AndroidManifest.xml
```

What's going on, please? Can I somehow see based on what file dates is `make` making a decision to rebuild it all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a known bug in r8c that causes full rebuilds even without any source code changes. See [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39810).

The suggested fix (not mine) is to change line 289 of build/core/definitions.mk from

`$1: $$(__ndk_file_dir)`

to

`$1: | $$(__ndk_file_dir)`

Comment: Applied the patch, it worked. For a better answer (and upvotes), you could paste the patch script here.

Comment: This is the fix. I also recommend setting the -j flag for make. See [this article](http://www.renderpaz.com/2012/12/speed-up-your-android-ndk-build.html) for a writeup. Short summary: add `<arg value="-j8">` to build.xml.

Comment: @glo: That's unrelated to this question. If you're unable to find a solution for that issue, feel free to post a _new_ question.

Comment: even build system have a bug.